# ExpressJS, route handling with two routers that also use each other?

Tags: node.js, express

I want to create route handling for these example routes:

```
GET /users
GET /users/:userid
GET /users/:userid/groups
GET /users/:userid/groups/:groupid

GET /groups
GET /groups/:groupid
GET /groups/:groupid/users
GET /groups/:groupid/users/:userid
```

Contrived code example of this setup. Imagine a directory structure as:

```
# index.js
# routes/users.js
# routes/groups.js
# lib/users.js
# lib/groups.js
```

And contents of each being:

**index.js**

```
express = require 'express'
UsersRouter = require './routes/users'
GroupsRouter = require './routes/groups'

app = express()

app.use '/users', UsersRouter
app.use '/groups', GroupsRouter

app.use (err, req, res, next) -> res.sendStatus(404)

app.listen '3000', () ->
    console.log "Listening on port #{3000}"

module.exports = app
```

**routes/users.js**

```
express = require 'express'
Users = require '../lib/users'
GroupsRouter = require './groups'

router = express.Router()

router.param 'userid', (req, res, next, userid) ->
    req.userid = userid
    next()

router.get '/', (req, res) ->
    Users.list req, (err, users) ->
        return next err if err
        res.status(200).send(users)

router.get '/:userid', (req, res, next) ->
    Users.find req, (err, user) ->
        return next err if err
        res.status(200).send(user)

router.use '/:userid/groups', GroupsRouter

module.exports = router
```

**routes/groups.js**

```
express = require 'express'
Groups = require '../lib/groups'
UsersRouter = require './users'

router = express.Router()

router.param 'groupid', (req, res, next, groupid) ->
    req.groupid = groupid
    next()

router.get '/', (req, res, next) ->
    Groups.list req, (err, groups) ->
        return next err if err
        res.status(200).send(groups)

router.get '/:groupid', (req, res, next) ->
    Groups.find req, (err, group) ->
        return next err if err
        res.status(200).send(group)

router.use '/:groupid/users', UsersRouter

module.exports = router
```

**lib/users.js**

```
module.exports =
    list: (req, cb) ->
        if req.groupid
            return cb null, "List of all users in group #{req.groupid}"
        else
            return cb null, "List of all users"

    find: (req, cb) ->
        if req.groupid and req.userid
            return cb null, "User #{req.userid} if in #{req.groupid}"
        else
            return cb null, "The user #{req.userid}"
```

**lib/groups.js**

```
module.exports =
    list: (req, cb) ->
        if req.userid
            return cb null, "List of all groups for #{req.userid}"
        else
            return cb null, "List of all groups"

    find: (req, cb) ->
        if req.userid and req.groupid
            return cb null, "Group #{req.groupid} if it has member #{req.userid}"
        else
            return cb null, "The group #{req.groupid}"
```

Problem is, I am getting an espress.js error for doing that cyclical require of the routers. Is it possible to do that?

If I instead just include one router in the other, and not vice versa, it get the expected response from my request.

An example of a longer route use case, say I want to see if a group has a user in it and if so return all the other groups that user belongs too:

```
GET /groups/:groupid/users/:userid/groups
```

Error I've received:

```
TypeError: Router.use() requires middleware function but got a Object
```

Comment: what do you have in your groups / user file? a function? you must pass a function to router.use, e.g. if you have a function routing() in your group/user file that you export, you would pass Groups.routing or call it, function(req, res, next){ Groups.routing(req, res, next); }

Comment: Both routers look very similar:

`express = require('express'); Users = require('../users'); router = express.Router(); router.get('/', function(req, res, next){}); router.get('/:groupid', function(req, res, next){}); router.use('/:groupid/users', Users); module.exports = router;`

Also to note - if I don't have the cyclical require - as in - I use the `users` routes in groups but not the `groups` routes in users, expressjs handles it fine.

Comment: requiring recursively wont work. The error msg you provided doesn't say that, though. Its more of a wrong argument error.because what you pass is not a function, its an object (router)

Comment: This sounds like you need to break the common-shared code into shared functions and put them in their own module and then both of your other modules can load the shared module and use those functions.  When programming with Express, people seem to think only of routes as the shareable unit, but you can create common functions that more than one route use and put those functions in their own module.

Comment: @jfriend00, The code that is called in the `/users` is a `Users.list(req, cb)` method. `/users/:userid` just calls a `Users.find(req, cb)`. Same with the Group routes (well, they would call the `Groups.list/find`).

So if a route is `/users/:userid/groups` I want to call the same method that `/groups` calls, in this case `Groups.list(req, cb)` that filters the list of groups who has the member `:userid`.

Same for the `/groups/:groupid/users`, I want it to call the same shared code that `/users` call, a list of users who belong to the `:groupid`.

Comment: I don't know what all that means. My point is that rather than A loads B and B loads A, break the common code out into C so that A loads C and B loads C.  Then, no circular dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to achieve the routing I wanted by exporting a middleware route from one router that I could assign to the route I want to match in another router.

**routes/users.js**

```
express = require 'express'
Users = require '../lib/users'

router = express.Router()

router.param 'userid', (req, res, next, userid) ->
    req.userid = userid
    next()

router.pseudo = router.use (req, res, next) -> next()

router.get '/', (req, res) ->
    Users.list req, (err, users) ->
        return next err if err
        res.status(200).send(users)

router.get '/:userid', (req, res, next) ->
    Users.find req, (err, user) ->
        return next err if err
        res.status(200).send(user)

module.exports = router

router.use '/:userid/groups', (require '../groups').pseudo
```

**routes/groups.js**

```
express = require 'express'
Groups = require '../lib/groups'

router = express.Router()

router.param 'groupid', (req, res, next, groupid) ->
    req.groupid = groupid
    next()

router.pseudo = router.use (req, res, next) -> next()

router.get '/', (req, res, next) ->
    Groups.list req, (err, groups) ->
        return next err if err
        res.status(200).send(groups)

router.get '/:groupid', (req, res, next) ->
    Groups.find req, (err, group) ->
        return next err if err
        res.status(200).send(group)

module.exports = router

router.use '/:groupid/users', (require '../users).pseudo
```

This routing setup allows for requests like:

```
GET /groups/:groupid/users
```

The route will set the req.groupid value from the group route middleware and then be routed to the users `/` route to list the users.

Same if you keep on daisy chaining them like:

```
GET /groups/:groupid/users/:userid/groups
```

The route will first hit groups, then users, then back to groups and giving me the set values for req.groupid and req.userid.

Answer (score 1):

`users.js` relies on `groups.js`, but then `groups.js` requres `users.js` while it is being executed. This means that it will go in a loop:

`users.js` calls `groups.js`

`groups.js` calls `users.js` which calls `groups.js` etc.

Answer (score 0):

This is the possible way to tackle this cyclic situation

keep the handler code in a separate module, and re-use in the route modules. (This is the point what [jfriend00](https://stackoverflow.com/users/816620/jfriend00) was also trying to make in comments)

for eg.

```
// userHandler.js

module.exports = {
  browse: (req, res) => {
    // return user list
  },
  find: (req, res) => {
    // return user
  }
}


// userRouter
// ... 
const handler = require('userHandler');
router.get('/', handler.browse);
// ...

// groupsRouter
// ... 
const uHandler = require('userHandler');
router.get('/:groupid/users', uHandler.browse);
router.get('/:groupid/users/:userid', uHandler.find);
// ...
```